# What physics engine would be good for a Silverlight pool engine?

Tags: c#, silverlight, pool, billiards

I have looked into the Farseer engine, but I barely scratched the surface.  Would it or another engine be good for a reasonably accurate pool game engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Farseer is your best bet, in my opinion.  It is the most supported and commonly used, and should easily be up to the task of a 2D game like pool.

Comment: Pool is not a strictly 2D game. Topspin and backspin require a third dimension.

Comment: True enough - it really depends on how much detail Ben is planning to add to his game.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comments.  Pool is part but not all of the game. I think that I can reduce some complexity and use just 2D based physics.